# Why are two images created instead of one?

Tags: docker

Please see the command below:

```
docker build -t iansbasecontainer:v1 -f DotnetDebug.Dockerfile .
```

It creates one container as shown below:

[image]

DotnetDebug.Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base

# Install the SSHD server
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openssh-server \
  && mkdir -p /run/sshd \
  && echo "root:Docker!" | chpasswd
#Copy settings file. See elsewhere to find them. 
COPY sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config
COPY authorized_keys  root/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Install Visual Studio Remote Debugger
RUN apt-get install zip unzip
RUN curl -sSL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh | bash /dev/stdin -v latest -l ~/vsdbg

EXPOSE 2222
```

I then run this command:

```
docker build -t iansimageusesbasecontainer:v1 -f DebugASP.Dockerfile .
```

However, two images appear:

[image]

DebugASP.Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM iansbasecontainer:v1 AS base
WORKDIR /app

MAINTAINER Vladimir Vladimir@akopyan.me 

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY ./DebugSample .
RUN dotnet restore 

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Debug -o /app

FROM base AS final
COPY --from=publish /app /app
COPY ./StartSSHAndApp.sh /app

EXPOSE 5000

CMD /app/StartSSHAndApp.sh
#If you wish to only have SSH running and start 
#your service when you start debugging
#then use just the SSH server, you don't need the script
#CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

Why do two images appear? Please note I am relatively new to Docker so this may be a simple answer.  I have spent the last few hours Googling it.

Also why is the repository and tag set to: .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Why do two images appear?**

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34151#issuecomment-316049721):

> When using multi-stage builds, each stage produces a new image. That image is stored in the local image cache and will be used on subsequent builds (as part of the caching mechanism). You can run each build-stage (and/or tag the stage, if desired).

Read more about multi-stage builds [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).

Answer (score 1):

Docker produces intermediate(aka `<none>:<none>`) images for each layer, which are later used for final image. You can actually see them if execute `docker images -a` command.

But what you see is called *dangling image*. It happens, because some intermediate image is no longer used by final image. In case of multi-stage builds -- images for previous stages are not used in final image, so they become *dangling*.

*Dangling images* are useless and use your space, so it's recommended to regularly get rid of them(it's called [pruning](https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/)). You can do that with command:

```
docker image prune
```